# vb.net build action question

Tags: vb.net

i have a question about the properties of build action of files in the project

the choices are compile, content, embedded resource, etc etc.

can someone please tell me the differences between all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I  think the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(VS.90).aspx) describes this fairly well.

Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: This was the most round-about Google search I've ever seen.